# How to get a list of rows from a database

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I'm trying to display some data this way from mysql in php:
CompteDAO.php

```
<?php
namespace DAO;
include_once(__DIR__ . '/bdConfig.php');

class CompteDAO
{
    public $bdd;

    public function getList(){
        $this->bdd = new \DAO\bdConfig();
        $requete = $this->bdd->bd->prepare('SELECT * FROM compte');
        $requete->execute();      
        return $requete;        
    }
}
?>
```

bdConfig.php

```
<?php
namespace DAO;

use PDO;

class bdConfig
{
    public $bd;

    public function __construct()
    {
        try
        { 
            $this->bd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=d', 'root', ''); 
        }
        catch (Exception $e) 
        { 
            die('Erreur: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
        }
    }
}
?>
```

index.php

```
$daoCompte         = new \DAO\CompteDAO();
$comptes           = $daoCompte->getList();

while ($data = $this->comptes->fetch()) {
    echo '<td>' . $data['CIN'] . '</td>';
}
```

But, doing this, I get no result. (Knowing that my database isn't empty) I think that the probelm is becoming from the getList return value, but I couldn't be able to found why and how to resolve it.

How do I fix this, please ?

Comment: In index.php, you're assigning the return value to `$comptes`, but then have `$this->comptes` in your while loop.

Comment: @andrewsi, I haven't understood what's wrong with that ?

Comment: `$comptes` and `$this->comptes` are two different variables. You'd be using the latter inside a class, which you don't seem to be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$daoCompte         = new \DAO\CompteDAO();
$comptes           = $daoCompte->getList();
$dataArray         = $comptes->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($dataArray as $data) {
    echo '<td>' . $data['CIN'] . '</td>';
}
```

you are not using class and you have no class property name `$comptes`. So `$this->comptes` is invalid.